# Problem with cutting sprites from a surface

Tags: surface, lighting, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

I want to create a lighting effect for my game. I did some research and I could do that by drawing a semi-transparent square and cutting out a circle or custom sprite. I looked through this tutorial here -> https://www.yoyogames.com/blog/476/quick-and-simple-lighting

My code runs, but it only shows the black screen and doesn't cut out the sprite from it. Is there something I am missing

```
CREATE EVENT
////////////
surface=-1;

DRAW EVENT
//////////
colortemp=draw_get_color();
cw=camera_get_view_width(view_camera[0]);
ch=camera_get_view_height(view_camera[0]);
cx=camera_get_view_x(view_camera[0]);
cy=camera_get_view_y(view_camera[0]);
if(!surface_exists(surface)){
    surface=surface_create(cw,ch);
    surface_set_target(surface);
    draw_set_color(c_black);
    draw_set_alpha(0);
    draw_rectangle(0,0,cw,ch,false);
    surface_reset_target();
}
if(surface_exists(surface)){
    surface_set_target(surface);
    //Draws the rectangle
    draw_set_color(c_black);
    draw_set_alpha(0.8);
    draw_rectangle(0,0,cw,ch,-1);
    //Draws the sprite
    gpu_set_blendmode(bm_subtract);
    draw_set_color(c_white);
    draw_set_alpha(1); 
    draw_sprite_ext(light_source,0,(player.x+player.sprite_width/2),(player.y+player.sprite_height/2),1,1,0,c_white,1);
    //Resets variables
    gpu_set_blendmode(bm_normal);
    draw_set_color(colortemp);
    draw_set_alpha(1);
    //resets target
    surface_reset_target();
    //Draws surface
    draw_surface(surface,cx,cy);
    //frees the screen to prevent memory leaks
    if surface_exists(surface){
        surface_free(surface);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the object set inside the room?

Comment: yes it is. I have the black background working, it just wont cut out the shape